# How to create case(switch) statement with a hash of constants using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, metaprogramming

I want to create the equivalent of this code, except using a hash and some meta programming.

```
def current_verb
  case params[:controller]
  when "apps"
    @current_verb = "MADE "
  when "articles"
    @current_verb = "LEARNED "
  when "articles"
    @current_verb = "WONDERED " # Change later to specify articles with a certain tag.
  else
    @current_verb = "IS "
  end
end
```

Intuitively, I tried something like this, but it seems to be invalid.
So far I have this in the application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :current_verb

  private
    verbs = { pages: "IS",
              apps: "MADE",
              articles: "TAUGHT", 
              articles: "WONDERED"
            }

    def current_verb
      case params[:controller]

      verbs.each |key, value| do
        # need this to spit out literal code, not evaluate code
        when key
          @current_verb = value
      end

      else
        @current_verb = verbs[:pages]
      end
    end
```

The tricky part about this is that I don't think I can use `define_method` or `send` because the looped portion isn't the entirety of the method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you have to generate static code, what's wrong with a simple method? Looking up hash values is a cheap operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just looking up a key in a hash and returning its value. The only caveat appears to be that if the ke isn't found then you want to return a default value of `"IS"`. I would suggest using [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) for this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  VERBS = { pages: "IS",
            apps: "MADE",
            articles: "TAUGHT", 
            articles: "WONDERED"
          }.stringify_keys.freeze

  before_action :set_current_verb

  private

  def set_current_verb
    @current_verb = VERBS.fetch(controller_name) { "IS" }
  end
end
```

Note that I made `VERBS` a constant so that it would be visible to the `set_current_verb` method. And I included it above the `private` designation because constants can't be private anyway. Using the `VERBS` hash inside of the `set_current_verb` method would cause it to be evaluated every single time, so the constant is a better solution still. Also, [`controller_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-c-controller_name) is preferred over `params[:controller]` for its expressiveness and because it will avoid returning namespaces should any exist in the future.

Also, the `VERBS` hash seems to have two identical keys. I assume that's just a typo and can be corrected by you.

Comment: SO enlightening. Thank you so much. This is so very much kickass programming. With your solution, I am currently only ever getting `"IS"`, regardless of the current controller I'm on.

Comment: The duplicate keys was a placeholder for triggering different values given different scopes of articles. I'll make another question if appropriate, but I wanted to have a subset of articles correspond to a verb string. The subsets could be via scopes or tags, i guess. I understand it's more complicated now because the controller name is not the only deciding factor now. What would be a more general method of achieving both controller and subsets of obtained models? And of course, better ways of accomplishing it are welcome too. (I'll make a new question and link it here.)

Comment: Ahh, everything returning `"IS"` is because `controller_name` is a string and the hash has symbols for keys. Can either use `controller_name.to_sym` or change the keys to strings in the `VERBS` hash. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Would either way be significantly better in terms of performance than the other?

Comment: Any more complicated than this logic and I would suggest writing a separate class or module to handle your article determination. Pass in the bits of info it needs to operate on from the controller and have the class break down the logic into chunks of responsibility.

Comment: It would be more performant to not cast the controller name to a symbol each time. So having string keys in the VERBS hash would be faster and use less memory. I updated the example to use `.to_sym` approach simply because I think the VERBS hash reads better using symbols :). Another option would be to do `VERBS = { ... }.stringify_keys.freeze`. Then you'd get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60896/discussion-between-gwho-and-pdobb).